# PHP-FPM fastcgi_finish_request reliable?

Tags: php, fastcgi

After implementing some post-processing in my php script after a `fastcgi_finish_request();` statement, I worry about some discrepancies.

Looks like PHP is not executing all the script after fastcgi_finish_request.

In the log files, I can not find a notice regarding this part, no warning, no error or irregularities.

Are there limitations or tips for using fastcgi_finish_request that are not mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Please provide some sample code that reproduces the problem.  Keep in mind that output from your script isn't possible after calling that function.

Answer (score 8):

Any explicit or implicit output flushing after calling fastcgi_finish_request() will result in exiting the PHP script without any warnings or errors. In other words, calling flush() after fastcgi_finish_request() has been called will behave like you had called exit() instead of flush().

[Here's a PHP ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68772) that documents the behavior. They've labeled it as "not a bug".

Here's some code that reproduces the issue:

```
function writestamp($case, $file){
  file_put_contents($file, "". $case . ": " . time() . "" . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}

// Flush buffers and stop output buffering
while (@ob_end_flush());

// Destroy session, otherwise request can't be finished
if(session_status() > 1) session_destroy();

$file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'flushbug_');
echo 'Writing 4 timestamps to: '.$file;

// this one gets called
writestamp('1', $file);

// and this
register_shutdown_function('writestamp', '4', $file);

// finish the request
fastcgi_finish_request();

// as does this
writestamp('2', $file);

// but this one does NOT - calling flush() after fastcgi_finish_request() exits PHP without errors or warnings
flush();
writestamp('3', $file);
```

A simple fix is to call [`ignore_user_abort(true)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) right before or after the `fastcgi_finish_request` call:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
fastcgi_finish_request();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. if you file a bug at php.net, please share the url. i will upvote for the fix. anyways, this strange behaviour only occurs with php5-fpm.

Comment: Considering that the stdout file handle has probably been closed by this method then writing to stdout is definitely an invalid operation.. You might try opening a buffer with `ob_start()` to see if it catches any output and thereby avoids the closed file handle issue.

Answer (score 2):

So far, for us, almost everything works after calling fastcgi_finish_request().  Except, error_log().  It does not log anything after calling this function.

Comment: This is because the logger is "closed" I think.

Answer (score 1):

To get errors log working set : **catch_workers_output = yes** IN your pool conf file **www.conf**

```
sed -i "s/;catch_workers_output = yes.*/catch_workers_output = yes/g" /etc/php/<VERSION>/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

`error_log` by default, write logs via fastcgi (thats why you see php log into `/var/log/nginx/error.log`), when calling `fastcgi_finish_request`, this will close the link between php-fpm and the fastcgi server (Nginx by instance) hence logs are written no where :/

You can specify log location according documentation at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-log.php.

Pay attention that the php worker is still alive, and can saturate the php-fpm pool.